# How to double click the item to open the default editor with the content by using ResourceNavigator in RCP?

Tags: eclipse, rcp

This is my navigator view.

```java
public class myNavigatorView extends ResourceNavigator {

private NavigatorActionGroup navigatorActionGroup;
private CollapseAllHandler collapseAllHandler;
public myNavigatorView() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}
protected void makeActions() {

    navigatorActionGroup = new NavigatorActionGroup( this );
    setActionGroup(navigatorActionGroup);

    IHandlerService service = (IHandlerService) getSite().getService(IHandlerService.class);
    service.activateHandler(IWorkbenchCommandConstants.NAVIGATE_TOGGLE_LINK_WITH_EDITOR,
            new ActionHandler(navigatorActionGroup.toggleLinkingAction));
    collapseAllHandler = new CollapseAllHandler(this.getViewer());
    service.activateHandler(CollapseAllHandler.COMMAND_ID,
            collapseAllHandler);
}
}
```

And when I double clicked the item I selected,the content didn't show in the editor.

```java
layout.setEditorAreaVisible(true);
leftFolder.addView("BIT_DEC.myNavigator");
```

Answer (score 1):

The resource navigator does this for open:

```java
protected void handleOpen(ISelection selection) {
    if (selection instanceof IStructuredSelection) {
        getActionGroup().runDefaultAction((IStructuredSelection)selection);
    }
}
```

So your action group `runDefaultAction` method needs to do the open. The resource navigator code does this:

```java
public void runDefaultAction(IStructuredSelection selection) {
    Object element = selection.getFirstElement();
    if (element instanceof IFile) {
        openFileAction.selectionChanged(selection);
        openFileAction.run();
    }
}
```

where `openFileAction` is an instance of `org.eclipse.ui.actions.OpenFileAction`.

Note: `ResourceNavigator` has been deprecated for a long time!

Comment: Sorry,how can I get the openFileAction? It pointed 'openFileAction cannot be resolved'.

Comment: And there's no 'org.eclipse.ui.actions'.

Comment: I tried what you said.But it appeared 'Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method selectionChanged(IStructuredSelection) from the type BaseSelectionListenerAction'.How canI solve it.

Comment: I solve it by reference to source 'OpenActionGroup.java'.Thank you.